# I would like to add a scalar to just one row of a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I created a *m-by-n* matrix [`Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat) and I would like to add a scalar to just one row of this matrix. In order to add a scalar to all elements of the matrix, you can use the following statement: `A += b`, where `A` is a `Mat` object and `b` in a scalar. But if I wanted to add a scalar to just one row of this matrix, how to perform this operation just as easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy:

```
image.row(i) += Scalar(...);
```

Taken from [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat):

> There are many different ways to create a Mat object. The most popular
>   options are listed below:
>
> ...
>
> Construct a header for a part of another
>   array. It can be a single row, single column, several rows, several
>   columns, rectangular region in the array (called a minor in algebra)
>   or a diagonal. Such operations are also O(1) because the new header
>   references the same data. You can actually modify a part of the array
>   using this feature
>
> ...